# trying to optimize a equation in the interval 1 to 4

Tags: r, optimization, equation

Trying to optimize a equation in the interval 1 to 4 but the minimum value of x and y is coming out to be wrong.

```r
x <- seq(from=1, to=4, by=0.1)
y <- ((x^2)+(54/x))
df <- data.frame(x,y)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_line()

optimize(y, interval = c(1,4))
```

[image]

RStudio window with code equation graph and minimum values of x and y

Comment: Please copy and paste your code so that your issue is reproducible, rather than take a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `optimize()` needs to be a *function*, e.g.

```r
optimize(function(x) {x^2 + 54/x}, interval = c(1,4))
$minimum
[1] 2.99999

$objective
[1] 27
```

If you print the value of `y` you'll see that it's a vector, not a function.  You could use `x[which.min(y)]` to find the value of `x` that corresponds to the minimum of the *particular* values of `x` that you have evaluated.